# How to use PHP classes from GitHub?

Tags: php

I am trying to do some PDF form filling. I found this PHP library:

https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk

However, I have never installed libraries before and am not sure how to proceed. I already have pdftk installed on the server. I read about autoload, and am familiar with functions like require_once, etc, but I am really not sure how to properly go about this. Any help is appreciated!

Regards

Comment: I am about to make several require_once calls but something tells me that is not how these github projects are meant to be incorporated in a website.

Comment: Suggestion: add what you tried in your question, this will make it better received by the community (this shows that you are not asking others to do the work for you).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this particular library,  but usually it is just enough to require_once on the library's main class.

Edit: The library uses Composer to resolve its dependencies.  You could do the same: https://getcomposer.org

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the project but if there are a ton of files then there is probably 1 that is using the rest as dependencies. What I mean by that is that there should be 1 file that you can require_once. See if there is a readme. That's usually my first step.